# How to make typescript understand that my variables are not undefined?

Tags: typescript

I got this code below, it works fine and do what I want, but if I move the if condition under a variable, typescript start to warn me that `fakeTradeInfo` and `fundsWeight` can be undefined.

```
// type of fundsWeight : SomeRandomArray[] | undefined
// type of fakeTradeInfo : SomeRandomObject | null

const StackOverflow = ({ row }: { row: INewTradeState }) => {
  const fundsWeight = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.fakeFund.fundsWeight[row.univers.uniqueid]);
  const fakeTradeInfo = useSelector((state: RootState) => getFakeTradesInfoById(state)(row.id));

  if (fundsWeight && fakeTradeInfo) { // Work fine
    return (
      <>
        <TextField variant="outlined" label="ccy" value={fakeTradeInfo.ccy} /> // Typescript doesn't warn about anything, work as expected
        <TextField variant="outlined" label="fx" value={fakeTradeInfo.fx} />
        {fundsWeight.map((fund) => (
          <>Do Stuff</>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
  return <>not loaded</>;
};
```

Here the "not working" code:

```
const StackOverflow = ({ row }: { row: INewTradeState }) => {
  const fundsWeight = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.fakeFund.fundsWeight[row.univers.uniqueid]);
  const fakeTradeInfo = useSelector((state: RootState) => getFakeTradesInfoById(state)(row.id));

  const hasLoaded = fundsWeight && fakeTradeInfo;

  if (hasLoaded) {
    return (
      <>
        <TextField variant="outlined" label="ccy" value={fakeTradeInfo.ccy} /> // <=== HERE typescript warn about the probability that fakeTradeInfo may be undefined
        <TextField variant="outlined" label="fx" value={fakeTradeInfo.fx} />
        {fundsWeight.map((fund) => ( // <=== SAME HERE 
          <>Do Stuff</>
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
  return <>not loaded</>;
};
```

How to make typescript know that hasLoaded mean that fakeTradeInfo/fundsWeight cannot be undefined/null ? I want to avoid the use of fakeTradeInfo!.ccy syntax.

Comment: create a new variable and store your previous variable as non-null in that: `var nnull = nullable!;`

Comment: try this `{fakeTradeInfo!.ccy}` or `{fakeTradeInfo?.ccy}` instead of this `{fakeTradeInfo.ccy}`, hope it will resolve the issue

Comment: I want to avoid the use of ? and !, it works without when I don't put my condition inside the variable

Answer (score 1):

**You would want to check if it's undefined before actually use it:**

```
<TextField variant="outlined" label="ccy" value={fakeTradeInfo && fakeTradeInfo.ccy} />
```

**Or using optional chaining**

```
<TextField variant="outlined" label="ccy" value={fakeTradeInfo?.ccy} />
```

Comment: It's not supposed to be undefined, I want to avoid this check that's why I posted this question

Comment: So I guess `!` is the only option. It's no harmful when you are sure when to use it.